# Как без списоков перемножить все нечетные числа между собой и вывести их в консоль?

Tags: python, циклы, for, числа, range

Необходимо используя `for i in range(1, 12)` перемножить все нечетные числа между собой и вывести их в консоль.
Списки использовать нельзя.

Как решить задачу не используя списки?

Comment: в вопросе уже написано, что именно нужно использовать!

Comment: Добавьте вариант со списками в вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На выбор:
раз:

```
pr=1
for i in range (1,12):
    if i%2!=0:
        pr=pr*i
print(pr)
```

два:

```
pr=1        
for i in range(1,12,2):
    pr=pr*i
print(pr)
```

Ответ в обоих случаях 10395
И оба раза -  без списков.
Правда, я не совсем понял, причем тут те списки были, но вам виднее.